# programatically change page of PDF using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to display a PDF within an iFrame, for a PHP, HTML and CSS based web "app" on the iPad. However, when viewing a PDF that's either in an object or in an iFrame, on the iPad, you can't change the page you are viewing. The scrolling just doesn't seem to work.

So my thought is that I need to create a next and prev button that uses javascript to change the currently viewed page. However, I can't seem to find any information on how to achieve this without embedding code in the PDF. This is not an option for the app though, as users will obviously not know how to embed code in the PDF's they upload.

I'd really love any information on how to achieve this solution w/o modifying the PDF's. Also, if there is an alternative to using an object or iFrame that will make this work on the iPad, that would be great too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using PDF.js

Their webpage can be found here: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

I didn't want to use their solution at first, because I heard it will have issues rendering some PDF's. However, so far, it appears to render our PDFs perfectly.

Here is some code I used to implement the process

```
PDFJS.getDocument('FILE_LOCATION').then(function(pdf) {
    state       = true;
    cur_page    = 1;
    total_pages = pdf.numPages;

    pdf.getPage(cur_page).then(function(page) {
        var scale    = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        var canvas  = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width  = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport:      viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });

    $(".pdf_viewer").on("click", ".prev_page", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( state && cur_page > 1 ) {
            --cur_page
            pdf.getPage(cur_page).then(function(page) {
                var scale    = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas  = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width  = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport:      viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
        }
    });

    $(".pdf_viewer").on("click", ".next_page", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( state && cur_page < total_pages ) {
            ++cur_page;
            pdf.getPage(cur_page).then(function(page) {
                var scale    = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas  = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width  = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport:      viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
        }
    });

    $(".pdf_viewer").on("click", ".close_window", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( state ) {
            state = false;
            pdf.destroy();
        }
    });
```

EDIT: fixed a typo

Comment: I also needed to assign the pdf.worker.js in the head of the html doc, as well as include the compatibility.js file in order to get this to work with Safari/iPads.